# Seaborn - purpose of sns.setstyle('ticks')

Tags: python, seaborn

What is 'ticks' supposed to do when styling graphs? I cannot find any difference between sns.setstyle('white') and sns.setstyle('ticks'). Below are a few examples from the internet:

[image][image]

White:

[image]

Ticks:

[image]

Comment: The official reference has an example of this, so I assume it is for use in decorating ticks. The image presented shows the default value of the tick whiskers.`set_style("ticks", {"xtick.major.size": 8, "ytick.major.size": 8})` [this page](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_style.html#seaborn.set_style)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that there are tick marks on the axes when you activate `style="ticks"` and there are not when you activate `style="white"`.

Comment: Thanks... can't believe I didn't notice!